# How to configure a ODBC connection to teiid on rhel8? GSSAPI negotiation fails

Tags: postgresql, odbc, rhel, teiid

I have a default Teiid 12.2 installation on RHEL 8.

Now I'm trying to configure an ODBC connection that would be used by PHP.

This always results in an error "[unixODBC]received invalid response to GSSAPI negotiation: R"

This is my ODBC configuration

```
[TEIID12]
Driver = PostgreSQL
Trace = No
Description = PostgreSQL Data Source
Servername = servername
Port = 35432
Protocol = 7.4-1
UserName = someusername
Password = xxxx
Database = vdb
ReadOnly = no
ServerType = Postgres
ConnSettings =
UseServerSidePrepare=1
Debug=0
Fetch = 10000
```

A regular isql command also fails with the same information

```
isql -v TEIID12 someusername xxxx
```

Results in:

```
[08001][unixODBC]received invalid response to GSSAPI negotiation: R

[ISQL]ERROR: Could not SQLConnect
```

Additional information:

- The same configuration used to work on a different Linux Distro (Ubuntu) but on this machine, kerberos was not configured. So I assume that this is influincing some sort of "preference".
- The `standalone-teiid.xml` configuration has `<ssl mode="disabled" />` for the odbc transport. And yet the GSS API errors occur.
- In combination with the later, is it possible that the postgresql ODBC driver is requiring GSS to be used? Is there a setting in odbc.ini where this can be disabled?
- On Ubuntu the driver version was 10.01, on RHEL it is 10.03

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution that worked was to set the environment variable `PGGSSENCMODE=disable` in `/etc/profile`.